# Synchronizing properties / fields between serialized classed on different AppDomains

Tags: c#, serialization, appdomain

So here is the situation - I have a class which derives from an abstract base class (and therefore can not be derived of MarshalByRefObject and used as a proxy object) and it is important that it has the proper state because it is dealing with a stream and doing some important things.

It is marked Serializable because I need to pass it in to another AppDomain and have that appdomain periodically call a `.Post(string)` method.

I do not know everything about appdomains, but i am seeing some weird things and I'm assuming that the class is actually getting re-instantiated with the same fields and properties in the second AppDomain and then I end up with multiple instances of the class.

This is a problem though, because when the second AppDomain calls `.Post()`, it makes modifications to the stream and it's own object state but the private variables contained within the class in the primary appdomain are not updated - so then there is a broken state in the primary appdomain and i end up with a corrupted stream as soon as the primary app domain calls `.Post` on its own version of the class!

I can not use a wrapper class either, because i need to pass the object casted as its abstract base class, and the second appdomain does not have any idea what the type of the derived class is, and only knows to call `.Post` which is an abstract method defined in the base class.

Is there any way to perhaps update the changes that the second appdomain made to the class back to the primary appdomain fields on command so that i can "sync" the state of the fields so to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a `MarshalByRefObject` wrapper class to do the job.

Consider the following example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("foo");

            FooFactory fooFactory = (FooFactory)appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, typeof(FooFactory).FullName);

            IFoo fooFromOtherDomain = fooFactory.CreateMeAFoo();

            string message = "Hello World!";

            Console.WriteLine("Data = {0} on AppDomain ID = {1}", message, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id);

            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            fooFromOtherDomain.Post(buffer);
        }
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Post(byte[] data);
    }

    public abstract class FooBase
    {}

    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents your class that can't be marshaled by ref...
    /// </summary>
    public class Foo : FooBase, IFoo, IDisposable
    {
        private MemoryStream _buffer;

        public Foo()
        {
            this._buffer = new MemoryStream();
        }

        public void Post(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

            this._buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            this._buffer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            OnNewData();
        }

        private void OnNewData()
        {
            string dataString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this._buffer.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Data = {0} on AppDomain ID = {1}", dataString, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._buffer.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps the non-remote Foo class and makes it remotely accessible.
    /// </summary>
    public class FooWrapper : MarshalByRefObject, IFoo
    {
        private IFoo _innerFoo;

        public FooWrapper(IFoo innerFoo)
        {
            this._innerFoo = innerFoo;
        }

        public void Post(byte[] data)
        {
            this._innerFoo.Post(data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For demo purposes to get an instance of IFoo from the other domain.
    /// </summary>
    public class FooFactory : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public IFoo CreateMeAFoo()
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            FooWrapper fooWrapper =new FooWrapper(foo);

            return fooWrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't be too concerned with FooFactory class. That was just to make it easy to remotely create an object that exhibits your scenario.

Essentially define an interface for your remote class, like `IFoo`.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Post(byte[] data);
}
```

Create a `Foo` wrapper class that is derived from `MarshalByRefObject` and implements `IFoo`

```
/// <summary>
/// Wraps the non-remote Foo class and makes it remotely accessible.
/// </summary>
public class FooWrapper : MarshalByRefObject, IFoo
{
    private IFoo _innerFoo;

    public FooWrapper(IFoo innerFoo)
    {
        this._innerFoo = innerFoo;
    }

    public void Post(byte[] data)
    {
        this._innerFoo.Post(data);
    }
}
```

Have your IFoo implementation passed to a `FooWrapper`.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
FooWrapper fooWrapper = new FooWrapper(foo);
```

Then return the `FooWrapper` to the other domain and call `IFoo` methods like `Post` as you normally would.

Output of the execution of this program:

[image]

Comment: This could work - but would take a lot of work, as right now everything is casted back to the type of the abstract class. In order to do this i would need to define a new interface and use that instead of the base class

Comment: @caesay- Only the public methods and properties you need to access across the domains needs to be in the interface. [Edit- I see what you mean, you're already referencing the base class in your calls and to refactor is a lot of work, are you using Visual Studio? It can help to refactor your code. Passing the base class across AppDomains is probably not the best thing to do anyway. Not as flexible as using interfaces]

Alternatively, do you control the abstract base class? Can you make it derive from MarshalByRefObject?

Comment: @caesay, if you cannot refactor your code to pass an interface instead of your base class, I'm afraid your options are limited but you could use some sort event relay that when values in one domain change, that change is relayed to its companion in the other domain and internally updates the values. This seems fragile though and more complex but if you can't refactor, then you need to have a shared remote object brokering the changes back and forth for you...

Comment: If it contained an internal class that derives from MarshalByRefObject would that be re-instantiated in the second appdomain or proxied over? It could be called on the setter of properties but im not sure how i would go about having it update other appdomain.

Comment: @caesay - No unfortunately that won't work. When an object is not MarshalByRefObject derived, it uses serialization which is essentially "by value" meaning when the instance is passed across the domain, serializes the object in the "sending" domain and then (deserializes) creates a new instance of the type in the "receiving" domain and proceeds to set each of the properties. So even an internal reference would be serialized this way. The only way to pass "by ref" is to derive from MarshalByRefObject. I really think extracting a public interface and refactoring would be in your best interest.